# How to support Backward Comparability for the type of param in REST APIs

Tags: java, rest, jackson, cxf, backwards-compatibility

I've 40-45 REST APIs built using Apache CXF framework. I do have a parameter as `telehpneNumber` which is of type `Long` now I need to change it to `String` but also want that these should be backward compatible.

Current thoughts over it to create two rest controllers like `v1`(old) `v2(new) v2 will be accepting`String`format. Using adaptor pattern I'll proxy`v1`request to`v2`. But`telephoneNumber`param is used in various objects & places. I though of making it as a type of`Object` but this work as expected when it's about taking request, but it will not when I'll be returning response.

What will be the right approach to solve this kind of backward-forawrd compatibility issue ?

Currently my thoughts is similar to something as coded below:

```
class OldTelephoneRequest{
    Long telephoneNumber;
    //some more variables
    //getters & setters

}

class TelephoneRequest{
    String telephoneNumber;
    //some more variables
    //getters & setters

}

@Path("/rest/services/v1")
class OldRestAPI{


    @Path("telephoneDetails")
    public Response telephoneDetails(OldTelephoneRequest oldTelephoneRequest){
        //make proxy call to v2 which will accept telephoneRequst object
        //Convert telephoneRequst to newTelephoneRequst(which will have telephoneNumber as String )
        TelephoneRequest request=new TelephoneRequest(oldTelephoneRequest);

        return RestAPI.telephoneDetails(telephoneRequest)
    }
}



@Path("/rest/services/v2")
class RestAPI{


    @Path("telephoneDetails")
    public Response telephoneDetails(TelephoneRequest telephoneRequest){
        //business logic
    }
}
```

The above approach has issue is that I'll have to construct 40-45 constructors for each request which will basically convert from `oldRequest` to `newRequst`
Let me know what will be the better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to leave the design as is and let MapStruct do the mapping for you:

```
@Mapper
public interface TelephoneRequestMapper {

    TelephoneRequestMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(TelephoneRequestMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "oldTelephoneRequest", target = "telephoneRequest")
    TelephoneRequest oldTelephoneRequestToTelephoneRequest(OldTelephoneRequest oldTelephoneRequest); 
}
```

---

**For more information:**
   http://mapstruct.org/